# How do I save a blend in the 2.79 format in 2.8?

Tags: blend-files, file-format

Files written in the 2.79 format are openable by Blender 2.8, but backwards isn't possible.

Is it possible to save a file in 2.8 in the 2.79 format so that it is openable by both versions?

I know one such workaround is simply to save in an exported format (ie. FBX or DAE) and then re-import it into the older version, but I was wondering if there was a way to keep it as the `.blend` file format?

Comment: You could try with "Append"

Comment: Append works fine. Tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will seem crazy, but, select all of your object and CTRL+C on 2.80, open 2.79 and PASTE (ctrl+V) right on the viewport. I know right? I saw it on a blendCon